# getting incorrect running sum variance calculation in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a calculation
RUNNING_SUM(SUM([CurrMonth])/RUNNING_SUM(SUM([PrevMonth])))/100
it should give me the %
$1616409.73 / $986568.61 163.84%
but it's actually giving me 125.84%
if I change the date posted from actual day to business day it gives me 511.12%

both of these are not right.. does anyone know a better calculation I can write to give me the number that I need?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it...by moving one of the closing parentheses from the previous month to after the current month. RUNNING_SUM(SUM([CurrMonth]))/RUNNING_SUM(SUM([PrevMonth]))